# using 'define' keyword for a list in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I use the `define` keyword in oracle SQL for a variable to hold a list of numerical values.  Then use that variable to be used in a `select` statement?

I have this in a SQL file:

```
define uniqueIds= [124,546,785,144];

select * from DATA_IDS where ID IN ('&uniqueIds');
```

But when I run it it gives me this error:

**ORA-01722: invalid number**

I'm running these commands in `Oracle SQL Developer` IDE.

Comment: Not like that.  This is not python.   DEFINE is just a string substitution.  Search on here for "dynamic in list"

Comment: What client application are you using to run the SQL script? `DEFINE` is an [SQL\*Plus command](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#i1211130) (it also works in SQL Developer) that defines a substitution variable and works on the **CLIENT** (and not in the database); if you are using another client application then it likely will not support that command.

Comment: @MT0 Forgot to mention but I'm using SQLDeveloper IDE to run this command.

Comment: @OldProgrammer ah I didn't know it was just used for string substitution.  I'll search for that text to see what I can find here.

Answer (score 3):

> How do I use the `define` keyword in oracle SQL

`DEFINE` is not an SQL keyword; it is an [SQL*Plus command](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#i1211130) that declares a substitution variable in the SQL*Plus (or SQL Developer) client application.

The client application will evaluate the substitution variable locally and will effectively transform the SQL statement containing a substitution variable by performing a find-replace from the variable to its value.

You want:

```sql
DEFINE uniqueIds = 124,546,785,144

SELECT * FROM data_ids WHERE id IN (&uniqueIds);
```

Or, you can simplify the script and skip using a substitution variable and just use:

```sql
SELECT * FROM data_ids WHERE id IN (124,546,785,144);
```

---

Your code would generate a statement:

```sql
select * from DATA_IDS where ID IN ('[124,546,785,144];');
```

Assuming that `id` is a `NUMBER` then you are effectively trying to compare the `id` column to a string literal (and not to a list of numbers) which is why you get the error `ORA-01722: invalid number` (as the string literal cannot be implicitly cast to a number).